# Angular2 ngModel one character behind

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an input field where I want to validate the input after each keystroke. Ultimately I'd like to validate it when they click outside of the input field (not sure which DOM event to use for this). The problem is that the input is "lagging" behind by one character.

For instance, if the user types in "a", then the ngModel variable it's mapped to equals "". when they type in "ab", the variable equals "a".

Partial code of **create-item.component.ts**

```
export class CreateItem {
  public item: Item;

  constructor() {
    this.item = new Item();
  }

  onCheckItemInput() {
    // validate input on each keystroke
  }
}
```

Input field of **create-item.component.html**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="item.name"
  #spy pattern=".{3,255}" (input)="onCheckItemInput()">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: RC2.  We have it figured out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `blur` event is fired whenever a user loses focus with an input element.

Example: User clicks outside the input box.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="item.name"
#spy pattern=".{3,255}" (blur)="onCheckItemInput()">
```

I've created a simple plunker to demonstrate this

https://plnkr.co/edit/4wnanssu08WPRziMkh9d?p=preview

Comment: Sometimes I get myself in a hurry.  Excellent answer that suits all my needs.

Answer (score 0):

To have it changed while typing, you can use `(keydown)`.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="item.name"
  #spy pattern=".{3,255}" (keydown)="onCheckItemInput()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (change) event if you want to validate the input when the user clicks outside of the input field and use (ngModelChange) event if you want to validate each keystroke.